# Count the frequency of unique values in every pandas column using groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, scipy.stats

How can i get all unique values and their frequencies in each dataframe column using groupby?

I have tried  stats.mode which gives info on the most frequent value which i would like to expand with frequenices of other column values.

```
from scipy import stats 
source = pd.DataFrame({'col1' : ['A', 'A', 'A','A'], 
                  'col2' : ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b'],
                  'col3' : ['c','c','d','d']})
source.groupby(['col1'])[['col2', 'col3']].agg(stats.mode)
```

result:

```
col1 
                 col2         col3      
A                ([a], [3])   ([c], [2])
```

I would like to get:

```
col1 
                 col2               col3        
A                ([a, b], [3,1])    ([c,d], [2,2])
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a custom function:

```
def cust_mode(s):
    counts = s.value_counts()
    return list(counts.index), list(counts)

out = source.groupby(['col1'])[['col2', 'col3']].agg(cust_mode)
```

output:

```
                  col2              col3
col1                                    
A     ([a, b], [3, 1])  ([c, d], [2, 2])
```

Comment: Note that OP wants tuple instead of list data types

Comment: Cheers, as always smooth solution. Note: just `return list(counts.index), list(counts)`, not the list data types must be converted to tuples, but the values of the data frame

Comment: @ko3 damn I need sleep, but OP can figure this out easily ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
for k in df.columns:
    print(df[k].value_counts())
```

Gives you what you want. If you want to include nan, `dropna=False` between the parenthesis of the `value_counts`